# Laravel not logging in after getting response from API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was using Truecaller API to get user info from truecaller.

The API actually sends a post request to the website.
I used TruecallerController to receive information from the API.
The API is working fine and I am also able to store user information in my database. But when I used Auth::login($user), it does not work. It does not redirect too.

Here is my controller code(I have removed the redirect part as it is not my concern for now):

```
public function login(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'accessToken' => 'required',
        ]);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$request->endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$request->accessToken,
            'Cache-Control: no-cache'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        $res = json_decode($res, true);
        $name = $res['name']['first']." ".$res['name']['last'];
        $email = $res['onlineIdentities']['email'];
        $phone = $res['phoneNumbers'][0];
        $user = new User;
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->name = $name;
        $user->phone = $phone;
        $user->save();
        Auth::login($user); //This is not working
    }
```

The code inserts the user data in the database, it just does not Authorise the user.

I have tried:

1. Auth::login($user)
2. $request->session()->put('user',$user) -- This is not working too.
3. Uncommented the AuthenticateSession line from kernel.php.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: For making API call I recommend to use Guzzle instead of curl

Comment: You have specified too few information. What exactly is not working?
Your controller do not have any redirect response, why do you expect redirect?

Comment: Try `Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);` You also need to `return` the method successfully for this to work.

Comment: @112Legion Auth::login($user) is not working. Even after using return redirect()->route(/path/) it does not redirect.

Comment: @QumberRizvi tried, not working.

Comment: Can you please `dd($user);` and show the dump here (remove sensitive info, of course)? Also, are you getting any errors? I hope you're including 'Auth' at the beginning of the controller: `use Auth;`.